# How to edit element of List of Lists?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a:

```
var list = new List<List<MyClass>>();
```

`MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public double X { set; get; }
  public double Y { set; get; }
  public bool Unique{ set; get; }
}
```

Now I have a `double x` and `double y` and I want to find element of list with same `X and Y` and set `Unique` field to false.

I already find examples for search like:

```
var element = (from sublist in list
               from item in sublist
               where item.X == x && item.Y == y
               select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

But how to edit this element?

Sure I can do something like:

```
foreach (var myClsList in list)
{
  foreach (var myCls in myClsList )
  {
    if (myCls.X == x && myCls.Y == y)
    {
      myCls.Unique= false;
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't look nice.

Comment: How would you normally edit it?

Comment: Looks as nice, or "cool"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you really want to *group* elements by their `X` and `Y` properties and properly set the `Unique` properties inside these groups. Here are some initial thoughts:

```
List<Element> allItems = list.SelectMany(l => l);
var groups = allItems.GroupBy(element => new { X = element.X, Y = element.Y });
foreach (var group in groups) {
    bool unique = group.Count() == 1;
    foreach (var element in group) {
        element.Unique = unique;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems very unclear whether you want to edit one element, or the entire elements matching certain criterion.

For one element you do:

```
(from sublist in list
 from item in sublist
 where item.X == x && item.Y == y
 select item).First().Unique = false; //the default item will be null
```

This works, but quite ugly. Better:

```
var element = (from sublist in list
               from item in sublist
               where item.X == x && item.Y == y
               select item).FirstOrDefault();
element.Unique = false;
```

---

To change them all, use a `foreach`. Linq is not really for side-effects. It should be a side-effect construct. In your case I would do:

```
var query = list.SelectMany(sublist => sublist)
                .Where(item => item.X == x && item.Y == y);
foreach(var myClass in query)
    myClass.Unique = false;
```

If you really want side-effects and want to do it in linq style, you can better adopt a fluent style tweaking your `MyClass` like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public double X { set; get; }
  public double Y { set; get; }
  public bool Unique { set; get; }

  public MyClass Duplicate()
  {
    Unique = false;
    return this;
  }
}

// So you call:

var query = list.SelectMany(sublist => sublist)
                .Where(item => item.X == x && item.Y == y)
                .Select(item => item.Duplicate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on the overall structure:

Look at the Dictionary<> class.  This is designed to store a list of items which may be accessed via an arbitrary type.  To use it in this context:

- Remove Unique from your class.
- Make your class a struct instead so it is compared by value rather than reference (i.e. two distinct MyClasses with the same X/Y are considered the same)
- Instead of a list, use `Dictionary<MyClass, bool>`

(seem to need text here to create a code block)

```
public struct MyClass
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

var items = new Dictionary<MyClass, Bool>();

items[ new MyClass{ X = 3, Y = 7 } ] = false;
items[ new MyClass{ X = -12, Y = -24 } ] = true;

Assert.IsFalse( items[ new MyClass{ X = 3, Y = 7 } ] );
Assert.IsTrue( items[ new MyClass{ X = -12, Y = -24 } ] );

items[ new MyClass{ X = 3, Y = 7 } ] = true;
Assert.IsTrue( items[ new MyClass{ X = 3, Y = 7 } ] );
```

To clarify how Dictionary works:

- K is the "key" type; this is the type used to label the items you're storing in the dictionary and is used both when putting items into it and taking items out.
- V is the "value" type; this is the type you are storing.
- You can read or write the dictionary using an indexer:

  - var value = dictionary[ key ]
  - dictionary[ key ] = value
- Dictionary may be faster under some circumstances than manually iterating through the list as it internally may use any data structure it likes to search for matches, which may be faster for large datasets.  I believe it uses GetHashCode to shortlist matches, but that's likely unimportant in this context.